# Is there a way to get an operating system to report the mouse location to a USB device

Tags: operating-system, position, mouse, hid

I have a product that has a mouse interface.  I need the operating system to report the absolute position of the mouse pointer to another USB device.
Is there an HID descriptor that I can add to gather mouse info?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a special driver and service than can do that. It is not easy task.